# jQuery detect page width and apply a left & right value

Tags: jquery, html, apply

I´m trying to create a navigation that contain two navigation arrows, and I need them to be fixed and next to a content div (one on the left and the other on the right)

Here is the example 
http://deals.bestbuy.com/#!/midweek+deals

I have the main divs this way

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="leftArrow"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
<dir id="rigthArrow"></dir>

</div>
```

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

PS: If you could tell me how to make the fixed position an absolute position on a certain scroll like that, that´ll be great.

PS2: "Sorry for le bad English."

Comment: are you ok with using jquery plugins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use plugin you can do this

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="leftArrow">Left</div>
  <div id="rightArrow">Right</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id='1'>Content first</div>
    <div id='2'>Content second</div>
    <div id='3'>Content third</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrapper {
   width: 60%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   position: relative;
}
#leftArrow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 13px;
    display: none;
    left: 85.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid;
     height: 70px;
    width: 50px;
}
#rightArrow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 13px;
    display: block;
    right: 12.5px;
    left: 525.5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid;
    height: 70px;
    width: 50px;
}
#content {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
 $('#content div').hide();
    $('#content #1').show();
    var index = 1;
    var count = $('#content').children().length;
    $('#rightArrow').click(function () {
        console.log('clicked');
        index++;
        if (index <= count) {
            $('#content div').hide();
            $('#content #' + index).show();
            $('#leftArrow').show();
        } else if (index > count) {
            index = count;
        }
    });
    $('#leftArrow').click(function () {
        index--;
        if (index > 0 && index <= count) {
            $('#content div').hide();
            $('#content #' + index).show();
        } else if (index < 1) {
            index = 1;
            $('#rightArrow').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Check [http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/WD67g/3//](http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/WD67g/3/)

If you want to use plugin you can search for jquery slideshow, few examples

http://www.slidesjs.com/

http://wowslider.com/rq/support-jquery-navigation-slider-1c.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer but this is not what I´m trying to do.
The navigation arrows works just fine. What I need is the switch between fixed and relative position. The opposite of this http://jsfiddle.net/wq2Ej/  

Check the navigations arrows in the bestbuy page when you scroll down.

Comment: Sorry it was: 
"Check the navigation arrows in the bestbuy page, when you resize the page the left & right values change, so the arrows stay next to the products div"